# Read an dynamic xml from dynamic asp script

Tags: c#, xml, asp-classic

I'm trying to read a dynamic xml who created by ASP script, but unfortunately I was unable to. It seems that my C# code can't understand the ASP script.

I'll be happy to hear some suggestions.

You can see the ASP script here: http://www.ad-net.co.il/test.asp

```
<%
Response.Buffer = True
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
body = ""
body = body & "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
body = body & "<PROGRAM>"
body = body & "<EMAIL>email@gmail.com</EMAIL>"
body = body & "<USERNAME>username@gmail.com</USERNAME>"
body = body & "<PASSWORD>password</PASSWORD>"
body = body & "</PROGRAM>"
Response.Write(body)
%>
```

The C# code is:

```
private static void LoadXmlFromServerToProgram()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load("http://www.ad-net.co.il/test.asp");

            EMAIL = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("EMAIL").InnerText;
            USERNAME = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("USERNAME").InnerText;
            PASSWORD = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("PASSWORD").InnerText;                
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't Read From XML");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide details on problem you have (exception message, or what unexpected behavior you observe, ...). Also please consider making variable names camelCase, not ALL-UPPER-CASE.

Comment: Your sample C# code works perfectly in a new console app. (declaring your 3 variables as strings). Have you used the Visual Studio debugger to step through your code? http://imgur.com/m57JL

Comment: I've declaring it as a string but yet still won't working

Comment: What type of program are you running this? WinForms, Console, Asp.NET, ect. Also, what .net version?

Comment: WinForms....... framework 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You *shouldn't* use SelectSingleNode that way.. you'll need an XPath query, not a single top level node. [Look here for information on XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

You'll need to try something like this:

```
EMAIL = xDoc.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/PROGRAM/EMAIL").Value;
```

Comment: I've tried it but unfortunately it's still not working, thanks for you help, is there any other suggestions??

Comment: I still get the MessageBox ("Can't Read From XML"), it seem that it can't read it as an XML file

Comment: +1 for better XPath to use. Note that "You can't use SelectSingleNode that way.. it expects an XPath query" is wrong - "EMAIL" is perfect XPath query - so it can be used just fine with SelectSingleNode. It not going to produce results OP want, but it is not fault of SelectSingleNode method.

Comment: sorry I'm kind of new at C# can you explain more detailed how can I fix this problom?? :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov This is true, I guess I worded that wrong. Thanks for correction :)

Comment: I've tried xDoc.CreateNavigator().SelectSingleNode("/PROGRAM/EMAIL").Value;
 Still I got the massage "Can't Read from XML"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace TestApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.LoadXmlFromServerToProgram();

            MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Email: ", Email, "\r\n", "UserName: ", UserName, "\r\n", "Password: ", Password));
        }

        public static string Email { get; set; }
        public static string UserName { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }

        private static void LoadXmlFromServerToProgram()
        {
            try
            {
                XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xDoc.Load("http://www.ad-net.co.il/test.asp");

                Email = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("EMAIL").InnerText;
                UserName = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("USERNAME").InnerText;
                Password = xDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("PASSWORD").InnerText;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Can't Read From XML");
            }
        }
    }

    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 262);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, I can't understand what you wrote here, Iv'e tried to run your script, But I got so many errors, so if you can make it more simpler I'll be glad...

Comment: You said you were using winforms. So, I created a new Windows Forms Application project and used some of your code in the form (Form1). The code you see there is the entire Form1.cs (public partial class Form1 : Form...) and the Form1.Designer.cs (partial class Form1).

Comment: Even simpler, here is the project that you can download. http://silentblood.lexonian.com/TestApplication2.zip. Let me know if you have problems downloading it.